# Python can't get a shell response from a knife command

Tags: python, bash, shell, subprocess, knife

I have a configuration manager, which is a Chef instance, and right now I can pull a list of chef clients using python that uses a shell command and then its shell output to get a list of nodes within python. 
However, when I wanted to get a url for a chef server using a knife config file, python couldn't pull the information out. This is because the shell output was always an empty string. Even if I can execute the same command on the actual shell terminal, I get the url.

I use subprocess module and python 2.7. I have no idea why this is the case since python manages to get the output of nodes easily compared to getting the url. So I was wondering if one of you fellow devs had faced this similar issue.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: I don't use `chef` or `knife` myself, but any chance it's printing to `stderr` instead of `stdout`?

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't get the error message, because python returned an empty string just like for the output.